# Translate exponents from base $2$ to base $10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> There are $10$ billion nerve cells with two states (on or off).
>   Assuming $2^{10} ≈ 10^3$, calculate the states of the brain in powers
>   of ten.

$2^{10^9}$ would represent $10$ billion nerve cells with two states each, correct?
So to translate do I simply do $10^{3^9}$ or is that an incorrect way to translate from one to the other?

Comment: "$(2^{10})^9$ would be $10$ billion (correct?)" - Wrong! "$2^{10^9}$ would be $10$ billion (correct?)" - Definitely Wrong!

Comment: Wait, why would you assume $2^{10}=10^3$?

Comment: @induktio: $2^{10}=1024\approx1000=10^3$.

Comment: @barakmanos Yeah I know, but that assumption seems a little...off-base (no pun intended).

Comment: And what does base $2$ have to do with anything? I don't see anything in binary except $10$, and I don't think you're interpreting this as $1(2)+0$.

Comment: @barakmanos  I updated the wording of the question. I didn't mean to say that was 10 billion. I mean it represented ten billion cells with two states each. The total number of states that the brain could take.

Comment: $2^{10B}=(2^{10})^B\approx(10^3)^B=10^{3B}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$10$ billion (in most varieties of English nowadays) is $10^{10}$, so you’re talking about $2^{10^{10}}$ states. $10^{10}=10\cdot10^9$, so

$$2^{10^{10}}=2^{10\cdot10^9}=\left(2^{10}\right)^{10^9}\approx\left(10^3\right)^{10^9}=10^{3\cdot10^9}\;.$$

(England used to use the long-scale billion of $10^{12}$; French *billion* and German *Billion* still have this meaning.)

Comment: I still prefer the logic of the English billion, but recognize the consensus meaning now in force :-(

Comment: Dr. Evil used the imaginary amount of $100$ Billion during the late 60s.

Answer (score 1):

Turning a comment into an answer:

$$2^{10B}=(2^{10})^B\approx(10^3)^B=10^{3B}$$